# Update local JSON file in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I am pretty new in Vue.js and I faced with the issue, that I can't update/write some data in my local JSON file.

Let's say that I have data.json
[image]

And I would like to add a new entry to this file.

I use the basic code :

```
  let d = JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 });
        const fs = require('fs');
        try { 
             fs.writeFileSync('data.json', d, 'utf-8'); 
            } 
         catch (e) 
            { 
            alert(e);
            }
```

As results I have an error message:

> "TypeError: fs.writeFileSync is not a function"

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `fs` is a Node.js module, are you sure you can use it in Vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue.js is a front-end framework. It runs in the user's browser, so it doesn't have direct access to files on the server. The `fs` module you're trying to use exists only in node.js, which runs on the server. That's why it appears to be undefined when you try to access it from your front-end vue code.

If you want to change files based on user actions, you need to set up a server for vue to send requests to, and have the server modify the files. Although, if you're trying to write changes to a JSON file, you probably want a database instead. Maybe take a look at MongoDB?